# Using dividerColor in Theme does not result in coloured Dividers

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, flutter-theme

I'm expecting that widgets in the display tree would be effected by a `dividerColor` having been set on my Theme in Flutter.

High up in my widget tree is:

```
MaterialApp(
  /* ... */
  theme: ThemeData(dividerColor: Colors.green)
  /* ... */
);
```

And yet when using a `Divider()` inside my child widgets, the colour is not present. Only when I set the colour explicitly, does it appear, like so:

```
Divider(color: Colors.green)
```

My understanding was that the Theme's `dividerColor` would be used when no colour is specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies; I had not restarted the application... ‍♂️

Posting answer here in case it helps anyone else; Theme changes need a full restart of the application as hot-reloading does not seem to have an affect when changing theme properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not solved yet on my flutter app. I have tried a **full restart** but divider color still black which is different than the `Theme.of(context).dividerColor`.

Comment: @KamranRamzan Likely that this is a separate issue.

Comment: Possibly, but i faced the similar problem and came to know that it was caused due to Material 3 adoption in flutter app. So I fixed it by supplying inline color to divider.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue when I migrated my app to use Material 3.

I fixed it by adding the `DividerTheme` to my `ThemeData` object.

```
dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(
  color: Colors.black12,
)
```